# @Formula annotation not understanding "count"

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an entity Group with a calculated property I'm trying to calculate with @Formula.

There's other three entities that have a foreign key to this entity, and what I'm trying to calculate is how many entities depend on each Group entity, so the formula looks like this:

```
public class Group {

...

@Formula("(select count (distinct (s.id)) + count(distinct(ses.id)) + count (distinct(u.id))
    from section s, session ses, user u, group_user gu
    where s.group_id = id and ses.group_id = id and gu.user_id = u.id and
          gu.group_id = id )")
    private int dependencies;
}
```

But when I perform a findAll on Group it throws the exception:

```
ORA-00904: "GROUP0_"."COUNT": invalid identifier
```

And the generated SQL looks weird, like this:

```
    Hibernate: select * from ( select distinct group0_.id as id1_8_, group0_.active as active2_8_, group0_.code as code3_8_, 
... 
(select group0_.count (distinct (s.id)) + count(distinct(ses.id)) + group0_.count (distinct(u.id)) from section s, session ses, user u, group_user gu where s.group_id = group0_.id and ses.group_id = group0_.id and gu.user_id = u.id and gu.group_id = group0_.id ) as formula1_ 
from group group0_ where 1=1 order by group0_.code asc ) where rownum <= ?
```

How should I write the formula to get it to work?

Comment: Well this supposedly works http://outbottle.com/hibernate-populating-an-unmapped-entity-field-with-count-using-formula/

Comment: `select count(distinct s.id) + count(distinct ses.id) + count(distinct u.id)` <-- try this syntax.  `DISTINCT` is _not_ a function, it's a keyword

Comment: In the end it was only a stupid problem: the gap between count and ( now it works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end it was only a stupid problem: the gap between count and ( if I write the formula:

```
@Formula("(select count(distinct (s.id)) + count(distinct(ses.id)) + count(distinct(u.id))
    from section s, session ses, user u, group_user gu
    where s.group_id = id and ses.group_id = id and gu.user_id = u.id and
          gu.group_id = id )")
```

It  works!!

Comment: I would still remove parentheses after `DISTINCT`.  That might fail on certain databases.

Comment: I removed distinct as I really didn't need the exact count but only to know if count is > 0